# Can a character use the Misty Step spell to stab someone without attacking?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, attack

One time, my sorcerer and my warlock were fighting. The warlock then used their Pact of the Blade and Hexblade ability to summon a rapier as an action, then as a bonus action used *misty step* to teleport right in front of the sorcerer with his arm sticking out.

At the time, I didn't make him roll to attack and let him roll for damage, but now I'm questioning it.

Can a character use the *misty step* spell to stab someone without attacking?

Answer (score 19):

## No

[Misty Step](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/misty-step) reads like this:

> Briefly surrounded by silvery mist, you teleport up to 30 feet to an **unoccupied** space that you can see.

The Sorcerer isn't an unoccupied space. You can't teleport yourself (which includes the equipment you're wearing) into him. You could teleport next to him and then do a regular attack, but this would require the use of the Attack action or another feature that'd give you an attack.

Comment: I agree. However, one could argue that since you are not wearing a readied sword, and that the sword can go into the occupied space even if you can’t. I’m not trying to be a smart Alec, so apologies if I come off like that.

Comment: @AustinCruce You have two options: Either "you" includes the things you're wearing and holding, in which case they can't go into occupied spaces either - or they don't, in which case they don't get teleported and you've turned Misty Step into an instant self-disrobement spell. You can't really have it both ways.

Comment: fair point. I guess I have my answer then